# Laravel 8 Basic Auth - Returning Recursion. UI Broken

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I installed basic auth with  TailwindCSS in Laravel 8 and it worked famously for several days.   Today,  I tried to get a hasOne relationship between users and roles working.  In the HomeController I began to experiment with Auth::user() and other related constructs.  At one point I placed a print_r to view the Auth::user() object.   It hasn't worked the same since because now it's always returning the print_r of the Auth::user().  I've cleared all caches including routes and optimized.  Now, neither does the login screen pop up nor home.blade.php, which it should on successful login.  Here is a sample of the output I'm getting.

```
 [this] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [1] => Closure Object ( [static] => Array ( [instance] => Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) ) ) [this] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [this] => App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider Object ( [namespace:protected] => [loadRoutesUsing:protected] => Closure Object ( [this] => App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider Object *RECURSION* ) [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [this] => App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider Object *RECURSION* ) ) ) ) ) [terminatingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [serviceProviders:protected] => Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) ) [3] => Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) ) [4] => Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( )
```

The HomeController Looks as Follows now:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index() 
{
    return view('home');
}
}
```

Any ideas how to get it working normally and showing the login ui?

Comment: Zoom would work.

Comment: What's your email?

Comment: work@mostafahana.com